# should I use IntentService or Service for UI update?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget, android-service

I'm wondering whether it makes any difference to use the `IntentService` class rather than the `Service` class in an android widget for managing UI updates (and registering `onClickListener`). Below is my code that I use `onHandleIntent` and `onStartCommand` respectively.

```
AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext());

int[] allWidgetIds = intent.getIntArrayExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS);

for (int widgetId : allWidgetIds) {onClickListener

    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.main);

    // Register an onClickListener
    Intent clickIntent = myIntent(this.getApplicationContext());

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, clickIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.text, pendingIntent);

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

By the way if you want to update UI threads during service calling it is not possible. But Android provides AsyncTasks to handle this kind of scenario. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html.